# Drawer ITem names Appearing as 0

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-fragments

[image]There is a problem Drawer item names, which are declared as array in strings folder. Whole program and code working fine. But at time of display action showing the right item click, but drawer item appearing image and text as zero.

The whole code for the above is followed below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.Igenesis.fliphound.slidingmenuadapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.Igenesis.fliphound.slidingmenu.NavDrawerItem;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Navigation_Bar extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Dashboards
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Campaigns
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Boards
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Accounts, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));



    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new DashBoardFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new CampaignsFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new BoardsFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new AccountsFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">FlipHound</string>
<string name="title_navigation_bar">Navigation_Bar</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="flip">fliphound</string>
<string name="loginpage">LOGIN</string>
<string name="loginpagesignin">SIGN IN</string>
<string name="loginpageonclick">SIGNING IN...</string>
<string name="checkboxlgin">Keep me logged in</string>

<style name="DefaultButtonText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#F5F6CE</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>

<string name="fliphound">Dont\'t have and account? Head over to
        &lt;a href=http://www.fliphound.com&gt;fliphound&lt;/a&gt; or call us now to get started.</string>

<string name="drawer_open">Slider Menu Opened</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Slider Menu Closed</string>

<!-- Nav Drawer Menu Items -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>DashBoard </item>
    <item>Campaigns</item>
    <item>Boards</item>
    <item>Accounts</item>
</string-array>

<!-- Nav Drawer List Item Icons -->
<!-- Keep them in order as the titles are in -->

<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/ic_dashboard</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_campaigns</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_boards</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_accounts</item>
</array>

<!-- Content Description -->

<string name="dashboard">DashBoard</string>
<string name="campaigns">Campaigns</string>
<string name="boards">Boards</string>
<string name="accounts">Accounts</string>

<string name="desc_list_item_icon">Item Icon</string>
```

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: You need to post your logcat in addition to your question, by editing it. Please remove it from answer.

Comment: What is the line number **80** in `Navigation_Bar.java`

Comment: mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

Comment: @Daya Post your `activity_main.xml` .

Comment: where is DrawerLayout in your xml file? check it first

Comment: @Jay wasn't displayed properly its there now :)

Comment: just comment navMenuIcons.recycle(); this line and then check.

Comment: Nope still leading to same exception

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, the main problem is in casting you used v4.widget.Fragment in xml and you directly cast it to in app.Fragment check your imports. you have to just replace

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

with

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

that's it...

Comment: nope in that case it will ask the java file to change whole fragment switch statement. I guess its not the prblem

Comment: developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip download this example and check it.

Comment: ITs been worked from the same code mate. There is some problem, unable to find it. ITs not with the imports though

Comment: i know thats silly thought but remove mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener()); and set it to after mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter); line.

Comment: send me your whole proj..if possible.

Comment: pass me your mail id please

Comment: jayeshkhasatiya@gmail.com